# Не завершается выполнение программы

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

При запуске кода взятого с сайта cvxopt программа не завершается и зависает на 5 строчке, все остальное работает отлично,

```
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers
c = matrix([-4., -5.])
G = matrix([[2., 1., -1., 0.], [1., 2., 0., -1.]])
h = matrix([3., 3., 0., 0.])
sol = solvers.lp(c, G, h)
print sol['x']
```

PS. Python2.7, Windows 10 x64